# Что за привилегии на Мете при получении 20к репы?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, локализация, справка, привилегии

На странице [привилегии 20к](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) есть раздел (последний) о привилегиях на Мете:

> [image: Мета-прив]

**N.B. Не обращайте внимание на красное выделение, оно не относится к сути вопроса, а всего лишь присутствует в справке.**

В [английской версии текста](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) ничего подобного я не нашёл. Более того, с некоторых пор со справочных страниц Мета сайта [осуществляется редирект](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291004/339911) на соответствующие страницы основного сайта.

Comment: Только избранным открывается эта фича (¬‿¬ )

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тому, что [пишет Ёж](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323708/can-we-mark-some-more-help-center-articles-as-moderator-editable#comment1058131_323708), до появления справки страницы с описанием привилегий были в каких-то вики страницах, которые могли править пользователи с 2k+ репутации.

Comment: Что-то ничего не понятно. Где пруфы и всё такое?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323708/can-we-mark-some-more-help-center-articles-as-moderator-editable#comment1058131_323708

Comment: В общем, весь раздел можно грохнуть.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ да можно весь сайт.

Comment: тогда негде будет предлагать его грохнуть :)